# Solving Equality Equation in c++

Tags: c++, int, double

I want to calculate maximum value(int) of i for which (i*(i+1)*(2*i+1))/3 < 4,294,967,295 (int limit).

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int i=1;
    unsigned int l=std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
    while(l>((i*(i+1)*(2*i+1))/3))
    {
        i++;
    }
    cout<<(i-1);getchar();return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation to make it easier to see the differences. Also, what `float` are you talking about?

Comment: There's no difference except a dramatically low parsing difference, what are you expecting from the above and what are you getting?

Comment: Run the code you will see the difference

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no conversion from float or double in any version, but they're both undefined due to signed integer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused comparing `unsigned int l` to an expression casted to `int`, this gives undefined results. In the second case the inner expression is all evaluated to an `unsigned int` and casted to `int` after evaluation (with a loss of precision that might cut the positive value). In your first case the nominator of the division function is casted to `int` *before* the division applies.

You should better write your condition like this, or even better omit the cast at all (there's no single `float` or `double` math operation done in your expression, you're dealing solely with `unsigned int`):

```
while(l>(unsigned int)(i*(i+1)*(2*i+1))/3) { // ...
      // ^^^^^^^^
```

If you do so, you'll always experience your loop running endlessly or very long. IMHO it makes no sense, to check if the result of the condition expression might be bigger than `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`, it **cannot** be bigger.

Comment: If you showed the cast to `int` this might make sense, since the type cast has higher precedence than arithmetic operations. But the way you are showing it, I think it should be the same.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm still not sure what the reason really is, you are right of course, it shouldn't make a difference. Could it be the expressions will at some point have temporary results with different precisions, or different points where an overflow could occur?

Answer (score 1):

This code will not give you the correct answer. The calculation can be rewritten as (i*(i+1)*(2*i+1)) < 3 * 4,294,967,295, now consider what that means about the calculation of the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality appearing in while loop is of order 3. this type of curve has very high slope,meaning small change in co-ordinate produces huge amount in y. while loop soon encounter in comparison of unsigned int and overflow of i, thus gives never ending loop(Yes never ending, i tried).

The solution is simple. break the in-equality in logarithm. Now the 3rd order polynomial is linear of log. Eventually it worked.

[image: VS]